# Visual Studio missing "create website" on start page

Tags: visual-studio, ide, settings

I recently imported a visual studio 2008 settings file.  This caused my "open website" and "create website" links to no longer appear under recent projects on the start page of visual studio.  I only have open project and create project.  When I goto File-->open I can select "website".  Just not from the start page.  How can I get those links back?

Comment: Should resetting the settings work?

Comment: Don't want to do that because then I lose the 99% of settings I do want.  In other words, I'd rather live with the way it is now then go back.  Just wondering if there is a quick setting I could use to get back those links.

Answer (score 1):

I don't get this option either - just Create -> Project...

Are you sure this ever existed? Of course; it isn't *that* often you create a new project/web-site. Perhaps just use File -> New -> Web Site... instead? - or:

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd>

Comment: I don't know, but I could imagine that Visual Web Developer Express has such a "link".

Comment: woah, kbd tag?  I never knew about that

Answer (score 1):

Go to Tools -> Import and Export Settings -> Reset all settings (save current settings if you like) -> Choose your default language (I chose VB.NET) and it should appear